# Confusion about Heine-Borel property on manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

I am studying Hopf-Rinow theorem in Petersen's book, and there is one of the four equivalent statements that confuses me.

$M$ satisfies the Heine-Borel property, i.e., every closed bounded set is compact.

And my question is, since manifold Hausdorff every closed set on it must be compact. So what makes the above statment special? Looking forward to someone's help.

Comment: The manifold $M$ itself need not be compact.

Comment: But it says closed bounded set, not the manifold itself.

Comment: $M$ is closed in $M$, but $M$ need not be compact.

Comment: The manifold $(0,1)$ has a closed subset which is not compact, namely $(0,1)$ itself.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!